# how to remove duplicate records from multiple excels files in python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 100+ files to verify for duplicates rows every day and After removing duplicates records have to rewrite that all files to the target folder. tried to make It for a single file & its working, Now whenever using for loop to read no. of files it giving me dictionary object not sure how to handle it with multiple files. I want to get all files written in excels only as it will be input to some other programs.

working code for a single file.

```
#reading files Source\Studentsheet1.xlsx        
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Source\Studentsheet1.xlsx')
#removing duplicates
df1=df.drop_duplicates()
#Now writing file to Target folder
df1.to_excel('C:\target\Studentsheet1.xlsx',columns=['StudentID', 'Class', 'Name', 'Section', Admission_date'],index=False, index_label=None)
```

sample data: Student Id:-SN0001 and SN0002 are duplicate rows

```
            StudentID    Class   Name    Section Admission_date 
    Index                                                                
    1       SN0001       XI      Chris     A     2017-06-01            
    2       SN0002       XII     Adam      B     2016-06-01           
    3       SN0003       X       Justyna   A     2018-06-01     
    4       SN0004       XI      Maria     B     2017-06-01     
    5       SN0001       XI      Chris     A     2017-06-01     
    6       SN0002       XII     Adam      B     2016-06-01
```

Comment: Use `df.drop_duplicates(subset='StudentID')`

Comment: What do you mean by this? `Now whenever using for loop to read no. of files it giving me dictionary object not sure how to handle it with multiple files.`

Comment: path = r'C:\Final_project\Source'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
print(type(filenames))
for file in filenames:
     df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, Header=None)
     print(type(df))

in this program reading all files in filenames(List ) then using for loop, in loop reading in df (dictionary)

Comment: Exactly what problem are you facing? Please include the formatted code in your question so that it can be easily understood.

Comment: thanks Scott for your suggestion but here I wanted to do it for 100+ sheets in one go, so trying using loops still not got the correct way of doing it

Comment: @Shubham, I am able to remove duplicate rows for a single file in one go, trying to do it for N number of files in one go( what I did for single file its code mentioned in the question

Comment: You collected unique data from source files to the target file , now target file has duplicates , Right ?! <br/>so why you do not filter target file as a final step!

Comment: @cb6033 Hmm. Are you getting any error while doing for N number of files?